# Administrator users can add records, end users can view them

Tags: views, forms

How can the administrator users add few records into the database (through a form), and how can the end users view them in the front end?

1. Administrator users will be adding records of training classes, through a form in an administration panel.
2. The end user will be viewing the list of training classes in the front end, in a block.

How to achieve these tasks?

Comment: any drupal geek existing here to answer my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here in short all the steps for the simplest solution I can think of:

1. depending on your content (needed fields...) you may need to create a new contentype (YOURCONTENTTYPE)(maybe using the [CCK module](http://drupal.org/project/cck) (drupal6))
2. make sure the roles are set correctly (e.g. admin can create and view this content, authenticated only view...) via `admin/user/permissions`
3. create a block (node-)view with the [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) where you filter by YOURCONTENTTYPE and sort by date
4. modify the visibility setings of this block via `admin/build/block` or in the view itself
5. admin can create content via `node/add/YOURCONTENTTYPE`

But it really depends on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal, there isn't a flag that set a page as administration page, and a tag that set a page/block for end users.

What makes a page for administrator users is the permission that users needs to have to see that page. A settings page requiring the users to have the permission to administer users is considered an administration page; the same is true for a setting page requiring the permission "administer content type," or "administer nodes."

If you have a page that needs to be seen only from administrators, then you need to use an existing administration permission, or implement a module that implement the specific permission that you need.
A block implemented by Views can use the permission implemented in other modules as well, and you can set the permission users need to have to view a block (or in general, a view) created with Views.